# How to store data most effectively and efficiently in iOS, especially for storing sticky note instance

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am developing an application for reading textual content. In that reader I need Sticky Notes feature just like iBooks. I want to save those notes within my device. How to save the entered text content? And how to re-open the entered text again (i.e) where/how to store the entered text?

```
UIMenuItem *item = [[[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Wikipedia" action: @selector(wiki:)] autorelease];
UIMenuItem *item1 = [[[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Dictionary" action: @selector(dict:)] autorelease];
UIMenuItem *item2 = [[[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Highlight" action: @selector(highlighting:)] autorelease];
UIMenuItem *item3 = [[[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle: @"Notes" action: @selector(noteMaking:)] autorelease];

[menuController setTargetRect:CGRectMake(100, 100, 320, 100) inView:self.view];
[menuController setMenuVisible:YES animated:YES];
[menuController setMenuItems: [NSArray arrayWithObjects: item,item1,item2,item3,nil]];

-(void) noteMaking:(id) sender
{
    notes = [[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 620, 520)];
    notes.text = @"";
    notes.scrollEnabled = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:notes];
}
```

Comment: Question is bit confusing, I lost the track of which text you are talking about :( could you please rephrase it. Thanks

Comment: I edited the question now. Is this understandable now for you? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you considered using CoreData? Does each note associated with each single page? or one page can have many notes?

Comment: I think this link will help you.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1391077/iphone-sdk-saving-large-amounts-of-text

Comment: One page can have many notes. User must be able to add notes where ever they want, and able to re-open it from the same place they saved the notes. Just like we having it in iBooks

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to store data on iOS. It all depends on which type of data it is and how much data you are willing to store. The best and reliable option is to store data inside CoreData. Which is basically **ORM (Object Relational Maping)**.

## Coredata:

[image] CoreData is the best and the most reliable frame work for data management. Specifically for very large amount of data. Foe you purpose I would recommend you to create database with book, page and note tables. CoreData will create entity classes from it and later you can persist data easily.

### Database:

[image]

You may change the attributes as per your need. However you don't have to strictly use Coredata. The other non-reliable option is to use. `.plist` files Which basically an XML files.

## .plist

[image] .plit files can be stored inside your Document directory and can be retrieve and save whenever you want. When you will read it will be parsed and you will get NSDictionary object which are easy to traverse. Although this is not a great option for you as you will be handling lots of data and the CRD operation will be very expensive.

## Conclusion :

Read through these links which has very detailed understanding about what you should use to persist data in iOD. The examples are given as well.

- [Apple CoreData example and understanding](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/iPhoneCoreData01/Articles/01_StartingOut.html)

## Tutorials from third party

- [Tutplus the great resource ever](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-sdk_store-data/)

Comment: my pleasure, if this solves your problem please accept the answer. But if someone else answers correctly please accept their answer. Thanks

Comment: Yeah sure. Thank you once again :)